# Form in Zend not submitting with <button> submit type only submits with <input>

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework

I'm updating a form in my zend project it's pretty basic. After updating the form to use a `<button type="submit">` tag it's not posting the form.

Does not work
`<button type="submit" name="Save">Continue</button>`

Works `<input type="submit" name="Save" value="Next">`

Part of the code in the controller which throws  the error is below, why is `$value = trim($value);` showing up empty when I post the form? All my fields and form action is correct I've tested everything and it's come down to the submit button type being the problem. Thanks

```
    $userSess = new Zend_Session_Namespace('Default');
    if (!$this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    $this->_helper->redirector('index','welcome');
}
$postData = $this->_request->getPost();
//validating form data, if empty data comes, redirect with err msg
    foreach($postData as $key => $value) {
        $value = trim($value);
        if($value == "") //if empty field submitted, redirect back with invalid msg
        $this->_helper->redirector('index','welcome',null,array('err'=>'Please Fill in all details'));
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this:

```
<button type="submit" name="Save" value="Next">Continue</button>
```

You have forgotten **value** attribute.
According to your code, if any input field has empty value, you execute redirect.
In your case, input field **Save** does not have a value (when you use `<button>` tag)

Comment: Thanks that worked. I thought the value in the input was only being used because it was an `input` value vs a `button` which had the value set between the tags. And that the values the code was looking for was data imputed into each field in the form.

Comment: Nothing to do with that, if value omitted, the text content will be used as value (+ older IEs doesn't use value attribute at all)